# "Delegate" hide action in jQuery? Can't match an easy element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The title's kinda messy, so I'll clarify here. I have a set of buttons which must interact which each other. For example when one clicks **Edit**, the button disappears and a **Save** button appears instead. There is another **Delete** button which actually deletes something, but while we're in *edit mode* (when the save button is present), the function of the **Delete** button switches and becomes the **Close** button for the *edit mode*. This is kind of a common scenario in the web world.

However, I have this little trouble with making the **Save** button disappear when it's clicked or the **Close** *edit mode* button is clicked. I can't make it vanish via jQuery!

So to break this up into steps, here is what it looks like:

- User clicks edit
- User gets some slight changes in the UI: Edit button vanishes and Save button appears
- User does what he wishes while editing
- User hits **Save** or **Close** to finish the editing
- The **Save** button still remains in the UI

I explicitly told jQuery to hide that button once the user is done and I've tried a million ways to hide it, starting with a simple `hide()` by using the class name as the selector and then using `e.delegateTarget`, but none worked.

**To see my problem in action, see this JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3272/

(Note the **Close** button in the right. I guess its position is `absolute` in Bootstrap 3.)

How do I make the save button vanish upon hitting **Save** (itself) or **Close/Delete**?

Comment: Tip: a common cure for iditis is to use common classes.

Comment: Do you want it to be *removed* or *hidden*? If you want it to be hidden, just add `$(this).hide()` within your `approve-edit` click event....

Comment: e.target.style.display = 'none';

Comment: @cale_b I tried it with `$(this)` but it didn't hide it. There is also the second case where the close/delete button hides the save button, so I can't obviously use `$(this)` there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even though e.target.style.display = 'none' will work.. I put a fiddle together (using pure JS) for you to review and adopt.

http://jsfiddle.net/brcaswell/52VtD/3278/

### JS

```
(function(window){
    window.ImgBoxTool = {
        'boxes': null,
        'init' : function () {
            ImgBoxTool.boxes = document.querySelectorAll('div.img-box');
            for (i=0; i < ImgBoxTool.boxes.length; i++) {
                ImgBoxTool.boxes[i].querySelector('button.edit').addEventListener('click', ImgBoxTool.Handlers.onEditBtnClick, false);
                ImgBoxTool.boxes[i].querySelector('button.save').addEventListener('click', ImgBoxTool.Handlers.onSaveBtnClick, false);
                ImgBoxTool.boxes[i].querySelector('button.close').addEventListener('click', ImgBoxTool.Handlers.onCancelBtnClick, false);
            }
        }
    }
    window.ImgBoxTool.Handlers = {
        'onEditBtnClick' : function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var image_id = e.target.id || e.target.parentElement.id || e.target.parentElement.parentElement.id;
            var elm = document.getElementById(image_id);
            elm.className = elm.className.replace('edit-mode','').replace('  ', ' ') + ' edit-mode';

            elm.querySelector('.edit').style.display = 'none';                    
            elm.querySelector('.save').style.display = 'block';

            elm.querySelector('.close').className = elm.querySelector('.close').className.replace('delete-img-box','').replace('  ',' ') + ' close-edit-mode';
            console.log('[ImgBox] %o \n\t %o',elm,e);
        },
        'onSaveBtnClick' : function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var image_id = e.target.id || e.target.parentElement.id || e.target.parentElement.parentElement.id;
            var elm = document.getElementById(image_id);
            elm.className = elm.className.replace('edit-mode','').replace('  ', ' ');
            elm.className = elm.className.replace('modified','').replace('  ', ' ') + ' modified';



            elm.querySelector('.edit').style.display = 'block';                      
            elm.querySelector('.save').style.display = 'none';

            elm.querySelector('.close').className = elm.querySelector('.close').className.replace('close-edit-mode','').replace('  ',' ') + ' delete-img-box';

            console.log('[ImgBox] %o \n\t %o',elm,e);
        },
        'onCancelBtnClick' : function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var image_id = e.target.id || e.target.parentElement.id || e.target.parentElement.parentElement.id;
            var elm = document.getElementById(image_id);
            elm.className = elm.className.replace('edit-mode','').replace('  ', ' ');

            elm.querySelector('.edit').style.display = 'block';                      
            elm.querySelector('.save').style.display = 'none';

            elm.querySelector('.close').className = elm.querySelector('.close').className.replace('close-edit-mode','').replace('  ',' ') + ' delete-img-box';
            console.log('[ImgBox] %o \n\t %o',elm,e);
        }
    }                                                                       
}(window));
        ImgBoxTool.init();
```

*Note: ImgBoxTool.init() needs to be run when the DOM is loaded.*

### HTML

```
<div id="1" class="img-box">
<hr />
    <button class="edit edit-img-box" aria-hidden="true">Edit</button>
    <button class="save approve-edit" aria-hidden="true">Save</button>
    <button class="close delete-img-box" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
</div>
<div id="2" class="img-box">
<hr />
    <button class="edit edit-img-box" aria-hidden="true">Edit</button>
    <button class="save approve-edit" aria-hidden="true">Save</button>
    <button class="close delete-img-box" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
button.close.delete-img-box {background-color:red;color:white;}

div.img-box {clear:both;overflow:visible;padding:1em;position:relative;min-height:8em;background-color:whitesmoke;border:0.1em outset whitesmoke;}
div.img-box:nth-child(even) {margin-bottom:1em;box-shadow:inset 0em -2em 8em -4em rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
div.img-box:nth-child(odd) {margin-bottom:1em;box-shadow:inset 0em -2em 8em -4em rgba(0,0,0,0.8);}
div.img-box:last-child {margin-bottom:0em;}

button {box-shadow:inset 0em -2em 2.5em -2em rgba(0,0,0,0.6);text-shadow:0.05em 0.08em 0.11em rgba(182,182,182,0.6);cursor:pointer;}
button:hover {}
button.save, button.edit {position:absolute;left:0;bottom:0;font-size:1.2em;padding:0.25em 0.5em;text-align:left;}

button.edit {display:block;}
button.save {display:none;}
button.close, button.cancel {position:absolute;right:0;top:0;display:block;font-size:2em;height:1.25em;line-height:1.25em;width:2em;}



div.img-box.edit-mode { background: orange; color: black;border-color: black;}

div.img-box.edit-mode > button.edit {display:block;}
div.img-box.edit-mode > button.save {display:none;}
div.img-box hr {box-shadow:0.1em -0.1em 0.7em rgba(0,0,0,0.2);position:absolute;top:2em;left:0em;right:0em;width:auto;}
div.img-box.modified hr { background: #f0c36d; color: #f0c36d;border-color: #f0c36d;}
```

Comment: note that I have console.log in the event handlers.. you'll probably want to remove that after you're done debugging.

Comment: jQuery should work fine. I've used it in these context before (that is, external js files that scope to window).. your problem was mainly because your approve-edit save button has 'edit' in the class name as well.. which you instructed to .show(); beneath your attempts at hiding the e.delegateTarget.. and so forth.

Comment: here.. I've updated your code to work by simply modifying your save button class to actually be "save approve-edit": http://jsfiddle.net/brcaswell/52VtD/3295/